# How to send basic data like a string from Android Studio to a Tomcat server?

Tags: java, android, tomcat

I am currently trying to figure out how to send a basic string to a Tomcat server through an Android application. I am using these programs:

- Eclipse IDE with Tomcat Server (Version 10.0.4);
- Android Studio;

What is the best method to do so?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629026/android-send-string-from-app-to-web-server

Comment: Tomcat is a WebServer, then i suppose what you are looking for is a HTTP request